# What classes in java are overriding equals() and hashCode() methods?

Tags: java

I know that String class has it own implementation for equals method?

Does it have its own implementation for hashCode() method as well?

Does Integer and other wrapper classes in java have their own implementation for hashCode and equals()?

Comment: yes, yes, yes and yes

Comment: Have you checked the source code yourself?  Look [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/String.java#String.hashCode%28%29) for `String#hashCode`.

Comment: This is trivially answered by looking at the JavaDoc or, if you're so inclined, the source code (which is in `src.zip` in your JDK directory).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taken from [here](http://www.programcreek.com/2011/07/java-equals-and-hashcode-contract/)

> The contract between equals() and hashCode() is:
>    1) If two objects are equal, then they must have the same hash code.
>    2) If two objects have the same hash code, they may or may not be equal.

Therefore: any class that defines `equals()` differently than `this == other` **must** have its own implementation of `hashCode()`